# How to execute a function from a component (<menu> </ menu>) and that the result is transferred to another component?

Tags: angular

This question may seem similar to others but I still cannot find the answer that makes my code work. I am using routes within my application. I have 2 components: `MenuComponent` and `PrincipalComponent`.

In `MenuComponent` I have a menu (it is injected into the app.component.html file and it shows a list of animals, and `PrincipalComponent` is my default route and it is the place where I would like to show the selected animal (click) in `MenuComponent`. I do not know how to send the response of the selected animal to `PrincipalComponent`, and show the selected animal.

[image]

This is my summary code, the link has my full code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-to5osq?file=app/menu.component.ts

```
export class MenuComponent  {
aAnimals=
[
  {"animal":"cat"},
  {"animal":"dog"},
  {"animal":"horse"}
]
Select a animal: <br> <button *ngFor="let item of aAnimals" (click)="getAnimal(item);" style="display:block;">{{item.animal}}</button>
export class PrincipalComponent  {
  animal:any;
  constructor(){

  }

  getAnimal(item){
    console.log(item);
    this.animal=item.animal;
  }
  <h1>animal selected: {{animal}}</h1>
```

Solving this question would solve many doubts and I could apply this logic when I create n pages and have a component that sends information to them.

Comment: when you has router, a "clasic" idea is using routing params, see https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service. You can see in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vtg6fp?file=app/principal.component.ts your idea working with routes. NOTE: I see that you use Angular 4, Why not use Angular 7? Angular 7 improve Angular 4 and has, e.g. the property state in NavigationExtras, see https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb that can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make share data between the component that is loaded in the `router-outlet` and the `<menu>`. The `<router-outlet>` emits an event `(activate)` which gives you the instance of the component that is loaded in the outlet. You can save this instance in your app component. Then using the events and parent-child relationship of the `AppComponent` and `MenuComponent`, you can set the value of the selected object to the `PrincipalComponent`.

See the working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szfj37)

Adding relevant code for reference.

### App.component.html

```
<router-outlet (activate)='onActivate($event)'></router-outlet>
<menu (setAnimal)='setAnimal($event)' ></menu>
```

### App.component.ts

```
private activatedComponent;
onActivate(component){
this.activatedComponent = component;
}

setAnimal(item){
    console.log(item)
    this.activatedComponent.animal = item.animal;
}
```

### MenuComponent

```
@Output() setAnimal: EventEmitter<any>;
constructor(){
  this.setAnimal = new EventEmitter();
}

selectAnimal(item){
  console.log(item);
  this.setAnimal.emit(item);
}
```